# PHP select From Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select

```
$calistir = mysql_query("select * from cevap INNER JOIN kullanici ON cevap.kullaniciID=kullanici.ID WHERE soruID=1 order by soruID ASC") or die("Hata Olustu!");
  while($oku=mysql_fetch_assoc($calistir))
  {
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"><?PHP echo $oku['isim']; ?></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"><?PHP echo $oku['soyisim']; ?></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"><?PHP echo $oku['cinsiyet']; ?></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"><?PHP echo $oku['yas']; ?></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"><?PHP echo $oku['cevap']; ?></td>
```

I have two tables.I used join.I wrote soruID=1 so my web page "SORU 2,SORU3,SORU4,SORU5" columns is null.I need write soruID=2,soruID=3,soruID=4 and soruID=5.How I can do this?
My webpage : altundus.com/ieee.php

Comment: could you specify what excatly you want to achive?

Comment: could you provide your tables structure and data samples ?

Comment: altundus.com/tables.png

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a printout like

```
isim  |  soyisim  |  cinsiyet  |  yas  |  cevap
  I1  |    S1     |     C1     |  Y1   |   CV1
  I2  |    S2     |     C2     |  Y2   |   CV2
  I3  |    S3     |     C3     |  Y3   |   CV3
```

etc... Remove the

```
WHERE soruID=1
```

from your join query, and make sure you add a closing `</tr>` tag to the end of the output block. This way, it should loop through each row in your result set, and print out a new table row for each result row.

Comment: did you check the link OP provided? I think he did `</tr>`. I guess he is asking about something different